# Error de conexión a base de datos remota desde servidor local (XAMPP)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, xampp, localhost

Hola estoy instalando un Wordpress en local con XAMPP pero mi base de datos la necesito tener en un servidor remoto, ya tengo la ip de servidor mi usuario y la base de datos creada pero al momento de hacer la instalación de Wordpress en local me da un error de conexión, adjunto captura.

[image: Error de conexión]

Cuales serían las recomendaciones o como podría habilitar esa conexión

Comment: Ya descartaste las tres recomendaciones ahí expuestas?

Comment: @Aprendiz si ya las descarte de hecho tengo instalado un wordpress en el servidor remoto y use las mismas credenciales

Comment: @Aprendiz Revise mi datos y están correctos, lo que quiero es conectarme a ese servidor para usar una base de datos que tengo ahí pero quiero tener el wordpress localmente

Comment: Por favor no publiques datos sensibles como la ip, esperemos a que alguien más te pueda brindar ayuda solo ten un poco de paciencia 

Comment: @Aprendiz Gracias por la recomendación, es un servidor de prueba no te preocupes lo destruiré lo más pronto posible solo resuelvo el tema

Comment: ¿Es posible que no tengas acceso al servidor de DB desde fuera? Es decir, por seguridad, muchos servidores bloquean el acceso si proviene de Internet.

Comment: @Roxgüel tengo otro servidor y he creado un wordpress y me he conectado al servidor de DB pero en local no me funciona, no se si tengo que activar algo en XAMPP

Comment: Entonces, ¿has probado con la configuración de tu Firewall?

Comment: @Roxgüel Ya he revisado la configuración de mi computadora y esta todo bien

Comment: Prueba [conectarte a través de Telnet](https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/Windows-10/1510815-Como-activar-Telnet-en-Windows-10.html). Con esta herramienta activa, abre una consola como `cmd` y escribe la palabra `telnet` seguido de la IP del servidor y el puerto para conectarte a la base de datos, algo como `telnet 111.222.333.444 1234` (respetando los espacios). Si obtienes un error, entonces el problema esta entre tu PC y el servidor

Comment: @Roxgüel Me sale este mensaje

telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Resource temporarily unavailable

Comment: Por lo visto no es posible conectarte con el servidor, al menos no a ese puerto. Te sugiero contactarte con tu proveedor de DB Server para que te brinde soporte. Por lo que puedo saber, desde tu PC no puedes conectarte, e intuyo que ha de ser por alguna medida de seguridad del servidor. Saludos.

Comment: @Roxgüel en efecto era configuración del servidor donde tengo alojada la base de datos, para resolver este problema fue necesario activar el puerto 3306 con el siguiente comando **/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mi problema era que mi servidor tenía **desactivado el puerto 3306** por lo que no podía configurar mi base de datos remota desde mi **Wordpress local**,

para **habilitar el puerto** se uso este comando que me brindo un desarrollador,

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

El servidor es un **Ubuntu 18.04**

Saludos!